# How to get rid of an additional key added while inserting a nested struct in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, go, struct, nested, tags

Suppose this is my struct definition,

```golang
type partialContent struct {
  key   string   `json:"key" bson"key"`
  value string   `json:"value" bson:"value"`
}

type content struct {
  id string `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
  partialContent
}
```

While storing the **content** in MongoDB, it gets stored as

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectID,
  "partialcontent": {
    "key": "...",
    "value": "..."
  }
}
```

But the JSON unmarshal returns

```json
{
  "_id": ObjectID,
  "key": "...",
  "value": "..."
}
```

How do I get rid of the additional key **partialcontent** in MongoDB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to export struct fields else the drivers will skip those fields.

If you don't want an embedded document in MongoDB, use the `,inline` bson tag option:

```
type PartialContent struct {
    Key   string `json:"key" bson"key"`
    Value string `json:"value" bson:"value"`
}

type Content struct {
    ID             string `json:"id" bson:"_id,omitempty"`
    PartialContent `bson:",inline"`
}
```

Inserting this value:

```
v := Content{
    ID: "abc",
    PartialContent: PartialContent{
        Key:   "k1",
        Value: "v1",
    },
}
```

Will result in this document in MongoDB:

```
{ "_id" : "abc", "key" : "k1", "value" : "v1" }
```

Comment: Thanks, this solves it! And sorry about the case, I forgot to add that in the question.